# Filtering XML file by ID

Tags: php, ajax, xml, rss

Hello I have a problem when I am trying to parse an XML file

I am trying to display only one song content using id for example

mysongs.php?id=0
It's supposed to show "I left my heart on Europa" song

and if mysongs.php?id=1

It's supposed to show "Oh Ganymede" song

I want use ID instead of the songs numbers
My problem is when I am using `[$id]` instead of the number `[0]` didn't work

```
echo $mysongs->song[$id]->title;
```

Please how can I fix my problem

This is my XML file content songs.xml

```
<album>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:40:26">
        <title>I left my heart on Europa</title>
        <artist>Ship of Nomads</artist>
    </song>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:27:42">
        <title>Oh Ganymede</title>
        <artist>Beefachanga</artist>
    </song>
  </album>
```

My PHP Code below

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$mysongs = simplexml_load_file('songs.xml');
echo $mysongs->song[0]->title;
?>
```

Comment: when you echo $mysongs->song[0]->title; what do you get

Comment: @NancyMooree, Hi, it's show the song name and it's work fine

Comment: can you post your full code including the xml file. you try the code below if you have id in the xml file 

    echo $mysongs->song[0]->id;

Comment: Can you make `var_dump($id)` ? That key might not exist. Either your id is too big  or it's a string.

Comment: @NancyMooree i update my question and my full code in the article

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa please give me an example using my code

Comment: There is no id column on your xml files.

Comment: @NancyMooree I know there are no ID column in my XML file but i want use the ID instead of the songs numbers

Comment: @NancyMooree, thanks for the help, but please one more question how can i echo the song number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set id as part of the column parameter within the xml files

Try code below

```
<album>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:40:26">
         <id>1</id>
        <title>I left my heart on Europa</title>
        <artist>Ship of Nomads</artist>
    </song>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:27:42">
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Oh Ganymede</title>
        <artist>Beefachanga</artist>
    </song>
  </album>
```

You can obtain the result using two method below

**1.) Using Direct Elements Method**

The following example gets the node value of the and  element in the first and second  elements in the ".xml" file:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$mysongs = simplexml_load_file('songs.xml')or die("Error: Cannot create object");
//get the first record
echo $mysongs->song[0]->id;
echo $mysongs->song[0]->title;

//get the second record
echo $mysongs->song[1]->id;
echo $mysongs->song[1]->title;
?>
```

**2.) using Element looping method**

```
 <?php
$mysongs=simplexml_load_file("songs.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($mysongs->children() as $song_album) {
    echo $song_album->id . ", ";
    echo $song_album->title . ", ";
    echo $song_album->artist . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I will also appreciate if you can upvote my answer. Thanks

Comment: I do not know what parameter that is holding your song number but lest assume its song_number. for exaple, it will look like <song_number>101</song_number> and you can then echo $mysongs->song[1]->song_number;

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a type issue.

Try to echo the type of your id, unless you parse it somewhere it will be a string:

```php
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo gettype($id);
```

Then, when you do `$mysongs->song[$id]`, it's not an equivalent of `$mysongs->song[0]` but of `$mysongs->song['0']` which is not the same index.

So, to have the expected output, you should cast it to int before using it as an index. For that, you can use either a cast (`$id = (int) $_GET['id'];`) or if it is not available in your PHP version [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.variant-cast.php) (`$id = intval($_GET['id']);`

Then the final result would look like to...

```php
<?php
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$mysongs = simplexml_load_file('songs.xml');
echo $mysongs->song[$id]->title;
```

Comment: please one more question how can i echo the song number?

Comment: Isn't that your ID? 
`echo "Song Number: $id"; echo $mysongs->song[$id]->title;`
But be aware that, if you change the order of the songs in your html doc, then it will also change the song number. If you intend to do that, @nancy's answer seems better.

Comment: I mean how can i echo the line number